# ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app'

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting below error in centos 7 when run gunicorn where i dont see any problem for windows, 
           from platform import create_app
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app'

```
from platform import create_app
app = create_app()
if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(debug=True)
```

Using:
Python 3.6.5
Flask 1.1.1
Werkzeug 0.15.5
gunicorn (version 19.9.0)

Comment: ├── config.py
├── platform
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── routes.py
├── setup.py
└── wsgi.py

Comment: @Matt Healy Please answer on this

Comment: @jman if you  can please help me?